# Attache different policies to different users in terrafrom

Tags: terraform

I have an `aws_iam_user` resource that creates users:

```
variable "users_list" {
  default = [
    "user1",
    "user2",
    "user3"
  ]
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "users" {
  count = length(var.users_list)
  name = "${var.platform}_${element(var.users_list, count.index)}
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "db_access" {

  count = length(aws_iam_user.users)
  user = element(aws_iam_user.users[*].name, count.index)

  name = "test1"

  policy = <<EOF
...
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "ec2_access" {

  count = length(aws_iam_user.users)
  user = element(aws_iam_user.users[*].name, count.index)

  name = "test2"

  policy = <<EOF
...
EOF
}
```

This way I can assign all these policies to all users

But for example, `user1` can have `db_access` and `ec2_access`, but `user3` could have only `db_access`

Is there any way to do this in terraform?

Comment: Which "policy resources"? You haven't shown any code related to that.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, `aws_iam_user_policy`.

Comment: Ok. So what exactly is the issue? Can you show you code for aws_iam_user_policy and why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin, I just update the code. Thank you